# Adding decimal to a number multiplies it by ten in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, floor

I'm having a problem with adding numbers in javascript. I have a variable that keeps track of full number (currentfloatx) and a variable that keeps track of the floored version of that number (newintx). I'm trying to add .25 to currentfloatx, but for some reason its multiplying the number by 10. Does anyone know why it's doing this? Is there something about how javascript is handling these number that I'm missing? Thanks.

```
//currentfloatx is currently set to 6
alert(currentfloatx + .25);   //returns 60.25
alert(currentfloatx);         //returns 6
newintx = Math.floor(currentfloatx + .25);
alert(newintx);           //returns 60.25
```

Comment: no, it does not. http://jsfiddle.net/LbUpA/

Comment: I get alerts of 6.25, 6, and 6, respectively. Exactly as expected. With an initial value of 6 for `currentfloatx`.

Comment: David - definitely not *=
Matt and Gacek - The jsfiddle returns the results that I would have expected. The code that I'm working with doesn't. The variable gets set by reading from a json array. Is there any reason how the variable was declared would have something to do with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I can think of that would make this happen is if `currfloatx` holds a string (eg., "6"). This would make `currfloatx + .25` be the equivalent of `"6" + "0.25"`, or `"60.25"`.

Comment: I'm guessing that this is whats happening. The number gets set originally from a json array, so I guess its reading it as a string instead of an integer. Thanks! I will accept the answer when it lets me.

Comment: @EricStrom Use [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to read the value it from the JSON array.